# SpecFlow - The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: automated-tests, specflow, azure-pipelines

I am facing a strange issue with my Specflow test scenario. In 'When' step, I am setting ScenarioContext as below to pass data:

```
ScenarioContext.Current.Add("mykey",ListOfStrings);
```

In 'Then' step,I am retrieving my collection from the scenarioContext as below

```
ScenarioContext.Current.Get<IList<string>>("mykey");
```

Its working fine on my local machine but when I trigger VSTS build it throw exception

> "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The Given key was not presented in the dictionary"

The reason I found for this exception is ScenarioContext dictionary becomes null in 'Then' step.
Though, in same project, other similar test case scenarios working fine where I am using ScenarioContext in same way. But in this specific test scenario I am facing this issue where SenarioContext get reset to null in 'Then' step and throw exception during VSTS Build. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What're tasks of your build definition? Which test framework you used for SpecFlow? Provide the details of your project.

Comment: Based on my test (unit test project with SpecFlow), it works fine, the item still exists in Then step, could you share the detail build log and a simple project on the OneDrive?

Answer (score 2):

The ScenarioContext inherits from Dictionary. When you debug, is this dictionary really empty? Do you have perhaps somewhere a ScenarioContext.Current.Clear() in your code?

My suggestion is to do not use the ScenarioContext for saving state, but to use Context Injection (http://specflow.org/documentation/Context-Injection/) for it.

Comment: Thanks Andreas for response. Dictionary is getting empty while running build in vsts and working fine while debugging locally. I am not using Clear() in my code.